# Saving Throws against Spells?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, difficulty-class

I've been playing a character in Pathfinder recently who is a divine spellcaster but does very little damage in combat, so I've been using a lot of debilitating spells (most notably [Terrible Remorse](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/terrible-remorse)) to stop enemies instead of fighting them head on, and letting party members deal with them.

The only issue is that neither my DM or I know the actual mechanics for determining Difficulty Classes, so we wind up doing a different thing each time. Is anyone familiar with the actual way it works?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From [The Pathfinder SRD page on the Cleric](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric) :

> The Difficulty Class for a saving throw against a cleric’s spell is 10
>   + the spell level + the cleric’s Wisdom modifier.

[The page on the Wizard](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard) has this :

> The Difficulty Class for a saving throw against a wizard's spell is 10 + the spell level + the wizard's Intelligence modifier.

So the generic formula for any spellcaster class looks like 10 + Spell Level + The class' Relevant Attribute for Spells.

Comment: The feat 'Spell Focus (Enchantment)' will bump up the DC for Terrible Remorse a bit too ;)